# Trouble with data frame shape

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, reshape

Right now, my data frame looks like this:
[image: messed up data frame]

It is shaped wrong - it is reading that 'Value' is the only column, and I need it to read as three columns: 'ZipCode', 'Date', and 'Value.'

We'll call it df for simplicity - how can I reshape this?
I have tried a .split method unsuccessfully, mostly because I got stuck on the fact that these are not strings ('Value' dtype is reading as an object).

I am not completely new to python but fairly new to time series and working on a homework assignment to forecast housing prices. This data frame was created as a result of resampling the data by year for each zip code - if that helps.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset your index without loosing it.

```
df.reset_index()
```

The values that are within the index will be moved to columns.

How you index your DataFrame depends on what you intend to do and how you want to search within your DataFrame. It will affect performance.

Comment: OMG I love you. So simple and yet it had given me such frustration. You're awesome.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept answer and make sure the string does not snap :-)